# A tricky probability question (About drawing balls from boxes)

Tags: probability

I found this question intriguing.

"In a box, there are 6 red balls and 7 blue balls. Two blue balls are drawn in the first and second draw. Assuming the balls are not returned, what is the probability of getting at least 2 red balls in the next three draws?"

How do you answer that question above?

I can't imagine how to answer this, because it felt like doing this:

"How to start a car, given that you have chopsticks on hand?"

I'm kinda weak at statistics and probabilities.

Comment: No results on google for your second question :)

Comment: Well after $2$ blues are drawn you just have a box with $6$ red and $5$ blue balls. To draw $2$ in the next three, you can draw red,red,anything or red,blue,red or blue,red,red. Those probabilities can easily be calculated.

Comment: @JohnLou LOL!!  math sucks. It's like doing it above; cars and chopsticks.....Especially to trick questions found in probabilities:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_1=P($red,red,anything$)=\frac{6}{11}\times\frac{5}{10}=\frac{30}{110}$

$P_2=P($red,blue,red$)=\frac{6}{11}\times\frac{5}{10}\times\frac{5}{9}=\frac{150}{990}$

$P_3=P($blue,red,red$)=\frac{5}{11}\times\frac{6}{10}\times\frac{5}{9}=\frac{150}{990}$

$P_1+P_2+P_3=\frac{19}{33}$

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard example. First of all note that in fact the initial situation is that there are $6$ red balls and $5$ blue balls in the box, because $2$ blue balls are already drawn.

Now you need to calculate the probability of drawing $2$ red and $1$ blue balls and the probability of drawing $3$ red balls.

**Probability of $3$ red:**

$$\frac{6}{11} \cdot\frac{5}{10} \cdot\frac{4}{9}$$

**Probability of $2$ red and $1$ blue:**

$$\frac{6}{11} \cdot\frac{5}{10} \cdot\frac{5}{9} \cdot \binom{3}{2}$$

Now it is only left to sum those probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

At the start, two blue balls are removed and not replaced. Thus, we can consider the problem to be "In a box, there are 6 red balls and 5 blue balls. What is the probability of getting at least 2 red balls in the next three draws?" I assume that the lack of replacement continues for this experiment.

Let's list the possibilities and associated probabilities.

"At least two red in the next three draws" means we can draw two or three red balls.

We could draw red balls on the first two draws, then a blue.

$P(RRB)=(6/11)(5/10)(5/9)=0.1515$

We could draw a red, then a blue, then a red.

$P(RBR)=(6/11)(5/10)(5/9)=0.1515$

We could draw a blue, then two reds.

$P(BRR)=(5/11)(6/10)(5/9)=0.1515$

Finally, we could draw three reds.

$P(RRR)=(6/11)(5/10)(4/9)=0.1212$

These possible outcomes are mutually exclusive, so we can add the probabilities: $P(\text{at least 2 red balls in 3 draws})=0.5758$.

Answer (score 0):

This question reduces to "What is the probability of getting at least $2$ red balls in the first $3$ turns (without replacement) from a bag of $5$ blue balls and $6$ red balls?"

The probability of getting at least $2$ red in the next $3$ turns is equal to:

1. The probability of $2$ reds $\dfrac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{11}{3}}$

plus

2. The probability of $3$ reds $\dfrac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{11}{3}}$

These two components sum to $19/33$.